# nginx regex - match variable number of fields

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a route with urls that can have an optional extra field. It can be either of the form :

- "/my-route/azezaezaeazeaze.123x456.jpg"
- "/my-route/azezaezaeazeaze.123x456.6786786786.jpg"

with :

- "azezaezaeazeaze" being a mongoId
- 123x456 two integers separated by "x"
- 6786786786 a unix timestamp
- jpg an image extension (could be jpeg, png, gif...)
- all those are separated by a "."

I would like to remove the optional part (the timestamp) from the request with the `http rewrite` module. So that the second url effectively becomes lie the first.

I made a small test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hD6zN0/4) to get the groups, but :
 - it doesn't seem to be the right syntax for nginx
 - I do not see how it will allow me to remove the timestamp

How can I remove the timestamp from that url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the right-hand end, you need to match a dot followed by anything
except a dot, so we have `(\.[^.]*)$`, then moving to the left, we want
to match a dot followed by only digits `\.[0-9]*`, which we dont want to
capture, and then to the left of that we want everything.
I ended up with something like this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\.[0-9]*(\.[^.]*)$ $1$2 ;
```

Comment: So it matches the url, but it is not rewriting it correctly. I am trying to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: sorry, `\1\2` was the syntax for the substitution in your  regex101 example. It should be `$1$2` for nginx. As to the flags, that depends on the rest of your setup.

Comment: Ah you are correct it seems, I accepted your answer. Would you say that your regex is more efficient than mine (since it seems more strict with the digits) ?

Comment: it's not particularly efficient as `.*` ends up matching too much and causes backtracking until `.[0-9]` matches. You might try versions using several `\.[^.]*` as they will progress without backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing on my first attempt and @meuh answer, I ended up with the following :

```
rewrite ^(/.*\..*)(\..*)(\..*)$ $1$3 last;
```

Now it works, but I would welcome any comment regarding the style/efficiency of this rewrite.